# Basic Java object class returning objects as null?

Tags: java, class, oop, object, getter

I just have a basic Class encapulating foods, and when i go to my client class to check the method `getName`, String and all the other methods, it all returns null. Not sure what is wrong here.

```
 public class Foods {

    public String name;
    public int calPerServing;
    public int servingPerContainer;

    Foods(String n, int c, int s){
        n = name;
        c = calPerServing;
        s = servingPerContainer;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name + "\nCalories Per Serving: " + calPerServing 
                + "\nServings Per Container: " + servingPerContainer;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getCalPerServing() {
        return calPerServing;
    }

    public int getServingPerContainer() {
        return servingPerContainer;
    }

    public int getTotalCalories(){
        return (calPerServing * servingPerContainer);
    }
}


public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foods chips = new Foods("chips", 10, 1);
        System.out.println(chips.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a typo:

```
Foods(String n, int c, int s){
    n = name;
    c = calPerServing;
    s = servingPerContainer;
}
```

Should be:

```
Foods(String n, int c, int s){
    name = n;
    calPerServing = c;
    servingPerContainer = s;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Dumb mistake but it happens.

Comment: @elisefinger you can reduce the change of it happening by making your member variables final wherever possible.